# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, game, rock-paper-scissors

A few days ago I made a "Rock Paper Scissors" game in C# and got my code reviewed on this site. Someone suggested writing a "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock" game and I did. I tried to follow the given advices but I'm not sure if this code is better or way worse than the other. I am not satisfied with my code and would be very grateful if you tell me how to write it better and also how I can learn to write cleaner, well-structured code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock
{
    public enum Choice
    {
        Rock = 1,
        Paper = 2,
        Scissors = 3,
        Lizard = 4,
        Spock = 5
    }

    public enum Opponent
    {
        None,
        Computer,
        Human,
    }

    class Rule
    {
        public Choice roundWinner;
        public Choice roundLoser;
        public string verb;

        public Rule(Choice roundWinner_in, string verb_in, Choice roundLoser_in)
        {
            roundWinner = roundWinner_in;
            verb = verb_in;
            roundLoser = roundLoser_in;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", roundWinner, verb, roundLoser);
        }
    }

    static class CompareMoves
    {
        private static Rule winningRule;
        private static bool? HasPlayerWon;

        public static Rule FindRulePlayer(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            return Game.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.roundWinner == p.Move_Enum && rule.roundLoser == cpu.Move_Enum);
        }

        public static Rule FindRuleCPU(ComputerPlayer cpu, HumanPlayer p)
        {
            return Game.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.roundWinner == cpu.Move_Enum && rule.roundLoser == p.Move_Enum);
        }

        public static Rule FindRule2P(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            return Game.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.roundWinner == p1.Move_Enum && rule.roundLoser == p2.Move_Enum);
        }

        public static void Compare(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            Rule rule1 = FindRulePlayer(p, cpu);
            Rule rule2 = FindRuleCPU(cpu, p);

            if(rule1 != null)
            {
                HasPlayerWon = true;
                winningRule = rule1;
                p.Score++;
            }

            else if (rule2 != null)
            {
                HasPlayerWon = false;
                winningRule = rule2;
                cpu.Score++;
            }

            else
            {
                HasPlayerWon = null;
            }
        }

        public static void Compare(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            Rule rule1 = FindRule2P(p1, p2);
            Rule rule2 = FindRule2P(p2, p1);


            if (rule1 != null)
            {
                HasPlayerWon = true;
                winningRule = rule1;
                p1.Score++;
            }
          
            else if (rule2 != null)
            {
                HasPlayerWon = false;
                winningRule = rule2;
                p2.Score++;
            }

            else
            {
                HasPlayerWon = null;
            }           
        }

        public static string WhoWonTheRound(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            if (HasPlayerWon == null)
            {
                msg = "\nTie.";
            }

            if (HasPlayerWon == true)
            {
                msg = string.Format("\n{0} wins this round. {1}", p.Name, winningRule);
            }

            if (HasPlayerWon == false)
            {
                msg = string.Format("\nComputer wins this round. {0}", winningRule);
            }

            return msg;
        }

        public static string WhoWonTheRound(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            if (HasPlayerWon == null)
            {
                msg = "\nTie.";
            }

            if (HasPlayerWon == true)
            {
                msg = string.Format("\n{0} wins this round.{1}", p1.Name, winningRule);
            }

            if (HasPlayerWon == false)
            {
                msg = string.Format("\n{0} wins this round.{1}", p2.Name, winningRule);
            }

            return msg;
        }
    }

    class Player
    {
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public int Move_Int;
        public Choice Move_Enum;
    }
    
    class HumanPlayer : Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public static void SetPlayerName(HumanPlayer p)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter name --> ");
            p.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void SetPlayerName(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            Console.Write("Player 1 - Enter name --> ");
            p1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Player 2 - Enter name --> ");
            p2.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public Choice PlayerMove(HumanPlayer p)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("\n\n{0} - Rock [1], Paper [2], Scissors [3], Lizard [4], Spock? [5] --> ",p.Name);
                p.Move_Int = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (p.Move_Int != 1 && p.Move_Int != 2 && p.Move_Int != 3 && p.Move_Int != 4 && p.Move_Int != 5);

            p.Move_Enum = (Choice)p.Move_Int;

            return p.Move_Enum;
        }
    }

    class ComputerPlayer : Player
    {
        public Choice ComputerRandomMove(ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            cpu.Move_Int = random.Next(1, 6);

            cpu.Move_Enum = (Choice) cpu.Move_Int;

            return cpu.Move_Enum;
        }
    }

    class Display
    {
        public static void MainMenu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the \"Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock\".\n");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.Write("Do you really want to play the game? [Y/N] --> ");
        }

        public static void Settings(HumanPlayer p)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Game.winScore = Game.HowManyPoints(ref Game.scr);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Play against the computer or an another player? [C/H] --> ");
            Game.opponent = Game.ChooseOpponent(ref Game.opponentStr);
            Console.Clear();
        }

        public static void Board(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t{0}: {1}\n\n\t\tComputer: {2}\n",p.Name, p.Score, cpu.Score);
        }

        public static void Board(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\t{0}: {1}\n\n\t\t{2}: {3}\n", p1.Name, p1.Score, p2.Name, p2.Score);
        }

        public static void Rules()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n  Remember:\n");
            foreach(Rule item in Game.Rules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

        public static void HumanVsCPU(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            Display.Board(p, cpu);
            Display.Rules();
            p.PlayerMove(p);
            cpu.ComputerRandomMove(cpu);
            Console.Clear();
            CompareMoves.Compare(p, cpu);
            Display.ShowMoves(p, cpu);
            Display.ShowTheRoundWinner(p, cpu);
        }

        public static void HumanVsHuman(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            Display.Board(p1, p2);
            Display.Rules();
            p1.PlayerMove(p1);
            Console.Clear();
            Display.Board(p1, p2);
            Display.Rules();
            p2.PlayerMove(p2);
            Console.Clear();
            CompareMoves.Compare(p1, p2);
            Display.ShowMoves(p1, p2);
            Display.ShowTheRoundWinner(p1, p2);
        }

        public static void ShowMoves(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} chose {1}.", p.Name, p.Move_Enum);
            Console.WriteLine("Computer chose {0}", cpu.Move_Enum);
        }

        public static void ShowMoves(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} chose {1}.", p1.Name, p1.Move_Enum);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} chose {1}", p2.Name, p2.Move_Enum);
        }

        public static void ShowTheRoundWinner(HumanPlayer p, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            string message = CompareMoves.WhoWonTheRound(p, cpu);
            Console.WriteLine(message);           
        }

        public static void ShowTheRoundWinner(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2)
        {
            string message = CompareMoves.WhoWonTheRound(p1, p2);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

        public static void AskForReplay(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            Console.Write("\nReplay? [Y/N) --> ");
            Game.StartGameOrNot(ref Game.startgame);
            Game.Initialize(p1, p2, cpu);
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }

    static class Game
    {
        public static string startgame;
        public static bool play;
        public const int MAX_SCORE = 50;
        public static int winScore;
        public static int scr;
        public static string opponentStr;
        public static Opponent opponent;

        public static List<Rule> Rules = new List<Rule>
        {
            new Rule(Choice.Scissors, "cuts", Choice.Paper),
            new Rule(Choice.Paper, "covers", Choice.Rock),
            new Rule(Choice.Rock, "crushes", Choice.Lizard),
            new Rule(Choice.Lizard, "poisons", Choice.Spock),
            new Rule(Choice.Spock, "smashes", Choice.Scissors),
            new Rule(Choice.Scissors, "decapitates", Choice.Lizard),
            new Rule(Choice.Lizard, "eats", Choice.Paper),
            new Rule(Choice.Paper, "disproves", Choice.Spock),          
            new Rule(Choice.Spock, "vaporizes", Choice.Rock),
            new Rule(Choice.Rock, "crushes", Choice.Scissors),
        };

        public static bool StartGameOrNot(ref string startgame_in)
        {

            bool play_in = false;

            do
            {
                startgame_in = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                if (startgame_in == "Y")
                {
                    play_in = true;
                }
                else if (startgame_in == "N")
                {
                    play_in = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("\nOkay then, goodbye.");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\nInvalid. Write \"Y\" or \"N\" --> ");
                }
            } while (startgame_in != "Y" && startgame_in != "N");

            return play_in;
        }

        public static int HowManyPoints(ref int winScore_in)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("How many points? [1-{0}] --> ", Game.MAX_SCORE);
                winScore_in = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (winScore_in <= 0 || winScore_in > MAX_SCORE);

            return winScore_in;
        }

        public static Opponent ChooseOpponent(ref string opponentStr_in)
        {
            Opponent opponent_in = Opponent.None;
            do
            {      
                opponentStr_in = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while (opponentStr_in != "C" && opponentStr_in != "H");

            switch (opponentStr_in)
            {
                case "C":
                    opponent_in = Opponent.Computer;
                    break;

                case "H":
                    opponent_in = Opponent.Human;
                    break;
            }

            return opponent_in;
        }

        public static void Initialize(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            p1.Score = 0;
            p2.Score = 0;
            cpu.Score = 0;
        }
        
        public static bool WhoWins(HumanPlayer p1, HumanPlayer p2, ComputerPlayer cpu)
        {
            if (p1.Score == winScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0} wins the game.", p1.Name);
                return true;
            }

            else if (p2.Score == winScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n{0} wins the game.", p2.Name);
                return true;
            }

            else if (cpu.Score == winScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nComputer wins the game.");
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Display.MainMenu();
            Game.play = Game.StartGameOrNot(ref Game.startgame);

            HumanPlayer player1 = new HumanPlayer();
            HumanPlayer player2 = new HumanPlayer();
            ComputerPlayer computer = new ComputerPlayer();

            Display.Settings(player1);
            Game.Initialize(player1, player2, computer);

            switch(Game.opponent)
            {
                case Opponent.Computer:
                    HumanPlayer.SetPlayerName(player1);
                    break;

                case Opponent.Human:
                    HumanPlayer.SetPlayerName(player1, player2);
                    break;
            }

            Console.Clear();

            while (Game.play)
            {
                switch(Game.opponent)
                {
                    case Opponent.Computer:

                        Display.HumanVsCPU(player1, computer);                      
                        break;

                    case Opponent.Human:

                        Display.HumanVsHuman(player1, player2);                       
                        break;
                }

                if(Game.WhoWins(player1, player2, computer))
                {
                    Display.AskForReplay(player1, player2, computer);
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Normally I was going to write lots of if-statements to compare moves but I think this way (which I found on another question) is better.

Comment: Are you aware there's such a thing as `else if`? Would be great for your `HasPlayerWon` comparisons.

Comment: @Mast OP is obviously aware of that. Just questionable, why they didn't use it for these specific conditional statements.

Answer (score 3):

### Namespaces

Have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125319/should-using-directives-be-inside-or-outside-the-namespace . I agree with StyleCop's default recommendation of moving `using` within the namespace:

```
namespace RockPaperScissorsLizardSpock
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
```

### Public members

If you leave these public:

```
    public Choice roundWinner;
    public Choice roundLoser;
    public string verb;
```

then there is no point to your constructor at all. The user can assign member values whenever they want. But that's not a great idea; it makes debugging and verifiability more difficult. Instead, keep your constructor, and mark these `public readonly`. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly for more details.

### C# now has interpolation!

```
string.Format("\n{0} wins this round. {1}", p.Name, winningRule);
```

can be

```
$"\n{p.Name} wins this round. {winningRule}"
```

### Integer intervals

```
p.Move_Int != 1 && p.Move_Int != 2 && p.Move_Int != 3 && p.Move_Int != 4 && p.Move_Int != 5
```

Assuming that this is non-nullable, then this should be

```
p.Move_Int < 1 || p.Move_Int > 5
```

That said, you're parsing user input in a somewhat non-friendly way:

```
int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

If a person enters a letter accidentally, this will explode with an exception. Consider `TryParse` instead, and deal with the failure case nicely.

### Side effects

`PlayerMove` does two things - sets the player's `Move_Enum` *and* returns it. To confuse things even further, you're modifying an argument player's move rather than `this`. I propose that you instead

- Do not return anything
- Do not accept a `HumanPlayer p`
- Set `this.Move_Enum` based on the input.

### Re-entrance

There's no reason for `Game` to be `static`. For testing purposes in particular, it's useful for this to be instantiated as a normal class.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the code so all references are "Player", not "Human and/or Computer" Your code will shrink by more than half.

---

**Do not use class name in method names**

In `ComputerPlayer`

- `ComputerRandomMove` would be `RandomMove`
- `SetPlayerName` : `SetName` (`Name` may be ok too )
- `PlayerMove` : `Move`

---

**Do not name classes as their inheritance chain**

`HumanPlayer : Player` should be `Human : Player`

That "Human" is a player is obvious.

---

**Inheritance and Polymorphism**

Yes, inheritance is used to extend a class - adding new properties and methods. But also and *far more important* is polymorphism - that is to say "all players do the same thing, but differently. All players have a name, but different names"

```
class Player {
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Move_Int;
    public Choice Move_Enum;
    public string Name {set; get;}
    
    public override Move(); // each subclass will have different implementation
}

Player Bob = new Human(...);
Player Hal2000 = new Computer (...);
```

No need for "Human vs Computer", "Computer vs Computer", etc. methods, just "Player vs Player"
So the only "Vs" method needed is:

```
 public static void Versus (Player ThisOne, Player ThatOne) {
 
     ThisOne.Move();
     ThatOne.Move();
 }
```

And is used thus:

```
Versus(Bob, Hal2000); //Bob is "ThisOne", Hal2000 is "ThatOne"
```

I expect that all subtype-specific-redundant-methods can be reduced to a single method: `Compare`, `WhoWonTheRound`, etc.

---

**overriding ToString()**

Big thumbs up!!!

I like toString() for outputting all the property values. Great for debugging. Also `WriteLine (Bob)`, for example, is actually calling `Bob.ToString()`

---

**Opponent Enum**

another thumbs up! And two thumbs up for `Opponent.None`.  I do this all the time.

I like the idea of an initial value of "not assigned yet", great debugging aid. If it defaults to "Human" it is harder to tell we forgot to assign the right kind. "None" forces explicit assignment.

You will appreciate this the first time you have an enum with lots of values.